# How to prove the convergence of the sequence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2 +1}{2n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition, infinity

Using the appropriate definition:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = + \infty \leftrightarrow \forall_{M\in \mathscr R} \exists_{ n_0\in \mathscr N+} \forall_{ n>n_0}$$ a_n> M$

check that the sequence diverges (that it converges to $+\infty$).

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^2 +1}{2n} $

Comment: What is the appropriate definition?

Comment: The definition is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = + \infty \leftrightarrow \forall_{M\in \mathscr R} \exists_{ n_0\in \mathscr N+} \forall_{ n>n_0}$$ a_n> M$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $M \in \mathbb{R}$, let $N=2 \lceil M \rceil$, then for $n>N$, we have
$$\frac{n^2+1}{2n} > \frac{n^2}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}>\frac{N}{2}\ge M$$

Answer (score 0):

write your term in the form $$\frac{n^2+1}{2n}=\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}$$ this tends to infinity, if $n$ tends to infinity
then you must solve the inequality
$$\frac{n^2+1}{2n}>M$$

Comment: the point is to prove it from definition not to find convergence at all